# How well is a variant in which Black moves first?

Tags: opening, chess-variants

Would it be good a chess variant if Black makes the first move instead of White? Notations will change, of course.

For example, since Black makes the first move with a king's pawn push of two steps, and White responding with a king's pawn push of two steps, it will become "1. e5 e4".

Answer (score 8):

It would be identical to current chess, except Black would obviously be playing White openings. The only difference is that the board would be inverted across the x axis.

[Magnus did this once in a #MoveForEquality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPFI3-W8Fqo).

Comment: Thanks. Without inverting the chess board, Black makes the first move instead of White.

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar, the point is that it is logically identical to usual chess, with the logical equivalence obtained exactly by reversing the colors, and "abstractly" flipping the board from left to right, to have the King and Queen locations be as usual...